# cypher NOT IN query with Optional Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

**NOT RELEVANT - SKIP TO Important Edit.**

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE (n:person) AND n.id in ['af97ab48544b'] // id is our system identifier
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:friend|connected|owner]-(m)
WHERE (m:person OR m:dog OR m:cat)
RETURN n,r,m
```

This query returns all the persons, dogs and cats that have a relationship with a specific person. I would like to turn it over to receive all the nodes & relationships that NOT includes in this query results.

If it was SQL it would be

```
select * from graph where id NOT IN (my_query)
```

I think that the OPTIONAL MATCH is the problematic part. I How can I do it?
Any advice?

Thanks.

**-- Important Edit --**

Hey guys, sorry for changing my question but my requirements has been changed. I need to get the entire graph (all nodes and relationships) connected and disconnected except specific nodes by ids. The following query is working but only for single id, in case of more ids it isn't working.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE (n:person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:friend|connected|owner]-(m) WHERE (m:person OR m:dog OR m:cat)
WITH n,r,m
MATCH (excludeNode) WHERE excludeNode.id IN ['af97ab48544b']
WITH n,r,m,excludeNode WHERE NOT n.id = excludeNode.id AND (NOT m.id = excludeNode.id OR m is null)
RETURN n,m,r
```

Alternatively I tried simpler query:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE (n:person) AND NOT n.id IN ['af97ab48544b'] return n
```

But this one does not returns the relationships (remember I need disconnected nodes also).

How can I get the entire graph exclude specific nodes? That includes nodes and relationships, connected nodes and disconnected as well.

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for all nodes connected to your :person that aren't :persons/:dogs/:cats connected by :friend/:connected/:owner relationships? Or are you trying to find all :persons where these relationships to those nodes aren't present? Or are you trying to find all nodes across your entire graph that do not include any of the :person nodes (and connected nodes) from your query? What's an example of desired output?

Comment: From your SQL statement and your problem description I infer you'd like to find all the `person`, `dog`, `cat` that are NOT connected to the `person` with the particular `id`?

Comment: Please read my last edit. Unfortunately my requirements has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

> match (n) where not n.id = 'id to remove' optional match (n)-[r]-(m) 
>   where not n.id in ['id to remove'] and not m.id in ['id to  remove']
>   return n,r,m

Answer (score 2):

You've gotta switch the 'perspective' of your query... start by looping over every node, then prune the ones that connect to your person.

```
MATCH (bad:person) WHERE bad.id IN ['af97ab48544b']
WITH COLLECT(bad) AS bads
MATCH path = (n:person) - [r:friend|:connected|:owner] -> (m)
WHERE n._id = '' AND (m:person OR m:cat OR m:dog) AND NOT ANY(bad IN bads WHERE bad IN NODES(path))
RETURN path
```

That said, this is a problem much more suited to SQL than to a graph. Any time you have to loop over every node with a label, you're in relational territory, the graph will be less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but the unwanted nodes yet returns as well

Comment: I edited slightly for cleanliness, but which unwanted nodes are you referring to? what is it returning that it shouldn't?

Comment: It returns 'bad' node itself

Comment: See update above. Add `*0..1` to the relationship to exclude the bad node.